# Remove duplicate values from an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to show data in array all but except the ones that are duplicates.

My array looks like this:

```
array (size=4)
       0 => string 'Eclairage Public' (length=16)
       1 => string 'Fonte de Voirie' (length=15)
       2 => string 'Aire de jeux' (length=12)
       3 => string 'Aire de jeux' (length=12)
       4 => string 'Fonte de Voirie' (length=15)
```

I want it to show only:

```
array (size=4)
       0 => string 'Eclairage Public' (length=16)
       1 => string 'Fonte de Voirie' (length=15)
       2 => string 'Aire de jeux' (length=12)
```

As you can see, the duplicate elements were removed. How can I accomplish this using PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/array_unique

Answer (score 1):

use **[`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/array_unique)**. It removes duplicate values from an array.

```
$arr = array_unique($arr);
```

Comment: Hasn't this already been answered *a lot* of times before? I don't think there's a need to answer every such question with "use `array_unique()`". The right thing to do would've been to close-vote the question as a duplicate (since you now have the CV privileges).

Comment: @AmalMurali IMO, both are appropriate. Answering the question and marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt: No, there's no need to answer obvious duplicates, vote for closure instead. See [this Meta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/).

Comment: @AmalMurali Cool, thanks for the link. I'll keep that in mind going forward :)

Comment: It's work well thank you too much .

Answer (score 0):

`array_unique` is what you looking for.

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```